# не получается повторить пример из книги г.Шилдт (Java)

Tags: java

книга г.Шилдт по java, стр176.
переписываю код из книги, но у меня показывает ошибку. Я так понимаю не видит метод в другом классе? обьясните

```
import javax.swing.*;

class box {
    double width, heigth, depth;
    double volume() {
        return width*heigth*depth;
    }
    void setDim(double w, double h, double d)   {
        width = w;
        heigth = h;
        depth = d;
    }
}
class  BoxDemo5 {
    public static  void  main(String args[]) {
        Box mybox1 = new Box();
        Box mybox2 = new Box();
        double vol;

        mybox1.setDim(10,20,15);
        mybox2.setDim(3,6,9);

        vol=mybox1.volume();
        System.out.println("Volume = "+vol);
        vol=mybox2.volume();
        System.out.println("Volume = "+vol);
    }
}
```

[image: этот пример в книге]

Comment: `но у меня показывает ошибку`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы класс назвали `box`, а используете класс `Box`. Вас не смущает, что у них регистр разный? Этот пример полностью работоспособный. Более того, что вы используете не то название класса, вы ещё и подключили не тот класс — из пакета `javax.swing.Box`. Ваш класс разве в этом пакете находится?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пакеты создали для того, чтобы отделять одинаковые названия (на самом деле не только из-за этого, но не хочу Вас грузить подробностями). Когда вы хотите использовать какой-то класс, то IDEA подсказывает Вам какие классы с таким именем существуют и указывают пакет в котором они находятся. Как видите, помимо вашего класса (он помечен `default package`) есть ещё `javax.swing.Box`, которые к вашему не имеет никакого отношения.

1. Переименуйте класс
2. Используйте класс из правильного пакета

P.S. Либо можете не переименовывать и оставить название класса `box` и в коде измените `Box` на `box`. Думается мне аналогов вашему классу с маленькой буквы не существует :) По Java Code Conventions классы **ДОЛЖНЫ** начинаться с большой буквы

Comment: спасибо, увидел, был не внимателен написав с маленькой буквы).
если верно понимаю, я не могу назвать класс Box потому что такой класс уже есть? поэтому для моих целей его лучше назвать другим именем.

Comment: Теперь такая ошибка(...не понимаю, что нужно cделать с классом main?
Error: Could not find or load main class com.learning_test.main

хочется больше изучать, практиковаться...а много времени уходит на поиск и решение каких то пустяковых ошибок(

Comment: Можете. Как я и сказал — **пакеты нужны для того, чтобы решать конфликты имён**

Comment: И если мой ответ Вам помог не забывайте оценивать его :) По поводу новой ошибки задавайте новый вопрос. Тут в комментариях я Вам не смогу подсказать. Может быть Вы что-то там написали не то)